# c++ multiple function on template?

Tags: c++, templates

New to c++ - kind of been cramming the last few days. Things are going pretty well! I do have one question though.

If I make a template:

```
template <class T>
T testFunc(T t1, T t2)
{
    // code code code code
}
```

My question, is the template <> line specific to that ONE function underneath? I couldn't continue to use the T placeholder in further functions could I?
like:

```
template <class T>
T testFunc(T t1, T t2)
{
    // code code code code
}

T testFunc2(T t1, T t2)
{
    // This one does other things....;
}
```

Comment: `T testFunc2(T t1, T t2)` is completely meaningless and `T` isn't related to anything (unless you have a class or struct named `T`). Did you mean to specialize a templated function for a particular type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when you declare

```
template <class T>
T testFunc(T t1, T t2)
```

This means that you are declaring a generic function "testFunc" which takes any class and works with it. To be honest, I don't really know how it can be useful. If you are defining your function in the global namespace then you can use as many template 's above your functions as you like. They are in now way connected.

You can make a generic class that takes another class as a template. That way you don't have to write "template " above every single method in your class. But your methods CAN take the type T as an argument.

Comment: This is what I was looking for - turns out it came up a few videos later in my pluralsight tutorials, but this made sense. I wanted multiple functions taking any type given, so if i make a template class with member functions this wrks